# What could be causing SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 5.1.7 Invalid address using java mail?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

Unfortunately, this is at a customer site, so we can't debug. Apparently it's been verified that both the to and from emails are valid. They are apparently using 'open authentication' because it is behind their firewall, so in that case our Properties and Session looks like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", configuredHost);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", configuredPort);
props.put("mail.smtp.auth.login.disable", "true");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setContent(messageBody, "text/html");
message.setSentDate(new Date());
```

This code is in use at other sites, and working. So what issue in their environment could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

The server disagrees with you about whether the address is valid.

You didn't include the code where you send the message so I can't tell if you're authenticating to the server.  If you're not, that may be why the server is rejecting your address.

Comment: There is no authentication, as I said in the original post. It apparently resolved itself. I think it was user error with the addresses.

Comment: note: if you think a question needs more detail/clarity, you are discouraged from answering it until that detail/clarity is added. see [answer].